# Django form meta and validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form:

```
class FindAdvert(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Advert
        fields = ('id', 'code')
```

But in this way I can't 'login' because validation return error: `id already exist`.
How modify this form to allow 'login' (instead of registration)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ModelForm for login, because it's semantical goal - create|edit database data (anyway you can hardcode `id` in your view - but it is wrong way).

So create simple `Form` with custom validation rules (in clean method or in your views), something like that below:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Username',
        required=True,
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Password',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()

        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')

        if (username and password and User.objects.filter(username=username).count() == 0)\
            or (username and password and User.objects.filter(username=username).count() == 1 and
                        User.objects.get(username=username).password != password):
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Wrong username or password')

        return cleaned_data
```

**views:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import FormView, RedirectView
# ... 

class LoginFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'common/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        logout(request)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_superuser:
            login(request, user)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('next') or reverse('human:add')

class LogoutRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(self.request)
        return reverse('common:login')
```